# Set Ansible fact with IPs from specific groups?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I currently have a fact set to:

```yaml
- name: Set nodes fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    nodes: "{{ groups['nodes'] }}"
```

Output:

```json
ok: [apollo.lan] => {
    "nodes": [
        "apollo.lan",
        "boreas.lan"
    ]
}
ok: [boreas.lan] => {
    "nodes": [
        "apollo.lan",
        "boreas.lan"
    ]
}
```

I would like to create another fact which stores the `ansible_default_ipv4['address']` values:

```json
ok: [apollo.lan] => {
    "node_ips": [
        "192.168.1.2",
        "192.168.1.3"
    ]
}
ok: [boreas.lan] => {
    "node_ips": [
        "192.168.1.2",
        "192.168.1.3"
    ]
}
```

I tried:

```yaml
- name: Set node IPs fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    node_ips: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4['address'] }}"

- name: Debug
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: node_ips
```

Output:

```bash
TASK [reset : Set node IPs fact]
ok: [apollo.lan]
ok: [boreas.lan]

TASK [reset : Debug]
ok: [apollo.lan] => {
    "node_ips": "192.168.1.2"
}
ok: [boreas.lan] => {
    "node_ips": "192.168.1.3"
}
```

I need the fact to contain a list of IP addresses, not just one. I don't know what is the correct way to do this, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtained the expected result with the following format:

```yaml
- name: Set node IPs fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    node_ips: "{{ nodes | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) }}"
```

Output:

```bash
ok: [apollo.lan] => {
    "node_ips": [
        "192.168.1.2",
        "192.168.1.3"
    ]
}
ok: [boreas.lan] => {
    "node_ips": [
        "192.168.1.2",
        "192.168.1.3"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why `set_fact` in that case? Declare your two variables in your play vars or even better in your inventory for the `nodes` group then simply use them. At the very least, use `run_once` on the fact task so that it assigns the same value to all hosts in play with a single run.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment on your self answer, this is how I would more efficiently manage the requirement:

Layout:

```
$ tree .
.
├── inventories
│   └── default
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── nodes.yml
│       └── hosts.yml
└── playbook.yml

3 directories, 3 files
```

Inventory file `hosts.yml`

```yaml
---
nodes:
  hosts:
    appolo.lan:
    boreas.lan:
```

Group variables file `nodes.yml`:

```yaml
---
nodes: "{{ group['nodes'] }}"
node_ips: "{{ nodes | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) }}"
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Basic demo for group vars
  hosts: nodes

  tasks:
    - name: Show vars where loaded for all hosts in nodes group
      debug:
        - "nodes value: {{ nodes }}"
        - "node_ips value: {{ node_ips }}"
```

which you can launch with: `ansible-playbook -i inventories/default playbook.yml`